# EF DbContext on a generic repository does not perform the expected includes when transforming the data into a list

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a generic/base repository that I'm using and it contains different variety of methods for accessing my database.

Here's a sample:

```
public IQueryable<T> FindAll(string[] includedProperties = null)
    {
        var setContext = _context.Set<T>();
        if (includedProperties != null)
        {
            foreach (var property in includedProperties)
            {
                setContext.Include(property);
            }
        }
        return setContext;
    }
```

I'm calling this method by:

```
var employees = _employeeRepository.FindAll(new string[] { "JobPosition", "Department", "EmployeeTeams", "EmployeeTeams.Team" })
```

When I perform a ToList() on employees, the expected navigation property is not included.

I tried switching it up and did the following:

```
var employees = _employeeRepository.FindAll().Include("JobPosition")
.Include("Department")
.Include("EmployeeTeams")
.Include("EmployeeTeams.Team")
```

And performing the ToList() includes the specified navigation property.

I want to make my approach on my generic repository work. Any ideas on how can I fix this?

NOTE: I also tried including navigation properties via expressions

```
(Expression<Func<T, object>> predicate[])
```

still the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include returns *IQueryable* (or *IIncludableQueryable* depending how you call it) so you need to add them after each other.

Try it like this

```
foreach (var property in includedProperties)
{
    setContext = setContext.Include(property);
}
```

Comment: I was actually trying to do this but it didn't crossed my mind that I can set the DbSet<T> to queryable. Thank you for this.